# помогите с кнопками добавления/удаления количества товара в корзине

Tags: javascript

не правильно работают кнопки добавления товара, добавляют null к уже существующему обьекту.

```
increaseCount (id) {
    const { products } = localStorageUtil.putProducts(id);
    products.count++
    shopPage.render()
   }

decreaseCount(count, id){
 const { products } = localStorageUtil.putProducts(id)
 if(count <= 0){
  return this.deleteItems
} else {
  products.count--
}
shopPage.render()
```

}

локалСтор

```
putProducts (id) {
let products = this.getProducts();
let pushProducts = false;
const index = products.indexOf(id);

if(index === -1) {
  products.push(id);
  pushProducts = true;
}else{
  products.splice(index, 1);
}
```

помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этой проблемой

Comment: id это случайно не объект у вас?

Comment: да, он приходит из локального каталога